# Populating a ListView from a Sqlite databse

Tags: java, android, sqlite, listview, cursor

I have been looking through a lot of tutorials and I still can't seem to find what I am looking for. I need to have the information that is stored in my *SQLite Database* shown in a *ListView*. I have the Database created and I know that it has the correct information in it, however when I look at the page with my *ListView*, nothing is there. The app doesn't crash and there aren't any errors, it's just empty. For reference, the *ListView* stuff is in the first thing of code and the *Cursor* for the Database is in the bottom of the second thing of code. Also, please note that I am fairly new to Android and I could be missing something quite simple.

Feel free to ask any questions and thanks for any answers!

Here are some pieces of my code:

```
public class Main_Screen extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

Button Test;
Button New;
ListView PassEntries;
DBHelper myDb;

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.screen_main);

    Test = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonTEST);
     // This button is meant to refresh the ListView
    New = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button10);
     // This button takes the user to a new screen where they input the data into the Database
    PassEntries = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

    openDB();
    populatePassEntriesFromDB();

    Test.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            populatePassEntriesFromDB();
        }
    });

    New.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
             myDb.close();
             Intent NewPass = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), NewPass.class);
             startActivity(NewPass);
        }
    });

}

private void populatePassEntriesFromDB() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Cursor CR = myDb.getAllRows();

    String[] fromFieldNames = new String[]
            {DBinfo.ACC_NAME};
    int[] toViewIDs = new int[]
            {R.id.nameView};

    ListAdapter Adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
                    this, 
                    R.layout.list_view_display,
                    CR,
                    fromFieldNames,
                    toViewIDs
                    );

    setListAdapter(Adapter);
}

private void setListAdapter(ListAdapter adapter) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

private void openDB() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    myDb = new DBHelper();
    myDb.open();
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
}
```

And my Database classes -

```
public class DatabaseOperations extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
public static final int database_version = 1;
public String CREATE_QUERY = "CREATE TABLE table_info ( " +
               "acc_name TEXT, "+
               "acc_pass TEXT, "+
               "acc_notes TEXT )";

public DatabaseOperations(Context context) {
    super(context, DBinfo.DATABASE_NAME, null, database_version);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    Log.d("Database operations", "Database created");
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sdb) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    sdb.execSQL(CREATE_QUERY);
    Log.d("Database operations", "Table created");
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

public void putInformation(DatabaseOperations dop, String acc_name, String acc_pass, String acc_notes)

{
SQLiteDatabase SQ = dop.getWritableDatabase();
ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
cv.put(DBinfo.ACC_NAME, acc_name);
cv.put(DBinfo.ACC_PASS, acc_pass);
cv.put(DBinfo.ACC_NOTES, acc_notes);
// cv.put(DBinfo.ACC_TYPE, type);
long k = SQ.insert(DBinfo.TABLE_NAME, null, cv);
Log.d("Database operations", "One raw inserted");

}

public Cursor getInformation(DatabaseOperations dop)
{
    SQLiteDatabase SQ = dop.getReadableDatabase();
    String[] coloumns = {DBinfo.ACC_NAME,DBinfo.ACC_PASS,DBinfo.ACC_NOTES};
    Cursor CR = SQ.query(DBinfo.TABLE_NAME, coloumns, null, null, null, null, null);
    return CR;
}
}
```

-

```
public class DBHelper {

public DBHelper()
{

}

public static abstract class DBinfo implements BaseColumns
{
    public static final String ACC_NAME = "acc_name" ;
    public static final String ACC_PASS = "acc_pass" ;
    public static final String ACC_NOTES = "acc_notes" ;
    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "acc_info" ;
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "table_info" ;
}

public void open() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

public Cursor getAllRows() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

public void close() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`PassEntries.setAdapter` -  you're not calling this method so you're not setting adapter to your `ListView`. `setListAdapter` method implementation is empty in your code. Delete empty `setListAdapter` method and call `PassEntries.setAdapter` instead of it. The next thing is `DBHelper.getAllRows` method returns just null in your code, but it should return the result of the query on your database as a `Cursor` object.

Comment: After changing it I'm getting these errors from Eclipse:  Syntax error, insert "VariableDeclarators" to complete 
  LocalVariableDeclaration
 - PassEntries cannot be resolved to a type

Comment: I set it like that and still got an error, however when I changed it to `PassEntries.setAdapter(Adapter)` it didn't give any errors.. Does that still work for what we are trying to do?

Comment: Okay, and on to the _Cursor_, what should the return type be?

Comment: Well, from `DBHelper.getAllRows` you should return `Cursor` as a result of query on your database, probably the result of method `getInformation` from your code.

Comment: I have been trying some different ways to do what you said and I can't even seem to manage to get a code without errors. Is it possible to explain it any further than this or am I just missing something obvious? @michal.z

Comment: Look here [Android Listview Example using CursorAdapter and SQLite database](http://www.mysamplecode.com/2012/07/android-listview-cursoradapter-sqlite.html). I'm posting you a simple example of the app which does exactly what you need - it gets data from SQLite database and populates it inside ListView. No more, no less. Just copy the code to your IDE, give it a run and learn from it. Afterwards simply modify it to fulfil your needs. This example really contains everything you need. Due to the fact I don't know what problems you encountered further in your code this is everything I can do.

Comment: Yes! I was able to look at that example code and I finally got a working code! I appreciate the help!

Comment: Great. I'm really happy you made it work and I'm glad I could help.